# Getting values(real value) from dynamic json object according to database records(place holders) and replace placeholders with real value

Tags: java, json, string, spring-boot, replace

In this code section I need to get values from dynamic json object according to database record. I've two tables on database called notification and placeholders many to many relationship and notification can contain dynamic number of placeholders and one service will send json post request to this services so that replace places holders with real value but since this service doesn't know about what are the number of dynamic placeholders real value should get from dynamic json array but json object contain notification id and using notification id I can get notification object and corresponding placeholders then I can get the real values from json object.

Here is dynamic json object.

```
{  
    "messageId":9,
    "msisdn":"94763703355",
    "<PACKNAME>":"Youtube",
    "<PACKTYPE>":"Social Media",
   
}
```

Here is a notification message related to messageId : 9

```
"You have succuessfully subscribe to <PACKNAME> and it will be <PACKTYPE> package"
```

This should be output :

```
"You have succuessfully subscribed to Youtube and it will be Social
Media package"
```

All placeholders should be replaced with relevant values but I'm unable to get expected output

@Service
public class NotificationServiceImpl implements NotificationService{

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
NotificationRepository notificationRepository;

@Override
public void getdata(String dynamicJson) throws IOException {


    // create object mapper instance
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    // convert JSON string to Java Object
    DynamicJson dynamicJson1 = mapper.readValue(dynamicJson, DynamicJson.class);

    // print user object
    //System.out.println(dynamicJson1);
    int id = dynamicJson1.getMessageId();

    Optional<Notification> notification = notificationRepository.findById(id);

    List<PlaceHolder> placeHolders = notification.get().getPlaceHolders();


    Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>();
    placeHolders.forEach(i -> replacements.put(i.getValue(), dynamicJson1.getPlaceholders().get(i).toString()));

   String message = notification.get().getMessage();

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(message.length());
    String delimiters = "+-*/(),. ";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(message, delimiters, true);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String w = st.nextToken();
        if (replacements.containsKey(w)) {
            result.append(replacements.get(w));
        } else {
            result.append(w);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());


}
}
```

Entity Class

public class DynamicJson {

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "DynamicJson{" +
            "messageId=" + messageId +
            ", msisdn='" + msisdn + '\'' +
            ", placeholders=" + placeholders +
            '}';
}

public DynamicJson() {

}

public DynamicJson(int messageId, String msisdn, Map<String, Object> placeholders) {
    this.messageId = messageId;
    this.msisdn = msisdn;
    this.placeholders = placeholders;
}

public int getMessageId() {
    return messageId;
}

public void setMessageId(int messageId) {
    this.messageId = messageId;
}

public String getMsisdn() {
    return msisdn;
}

public void setMsisdn(String msisdn) {
    this.msisdn = msisdn;
}

public Map<String, Object> getPlaceholders() {
    return placeholders;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAddress(String key, Object value) {
    placeholders.put(key, value);
}

private int messageId;
private String msisdn;
private Map<String, Object> placeholders = new HashMap<>();
```

}

Controller

@Autowired
NotificationService notificationService;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public void getObject(@RequestBody String dynamicJson) throws IOException {

    notificationService.getdata(dynamicJson);

}
```

This is what I get as output

```
You have succuessfully subscribed to Youtube and it will be <PACKTYPE> package

You have succuessfully subscribed to <PACKNAME> and it will be Social Media package
```

What I really need is

```
You have succuessfully subscribed to Youtube and it will be Social Media package
```

Placeholder and realValue element count is dynamic and 1 to n

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes but I was unable to figure out what went to wrong

Comment: It is your outer for loop.  You loop over your placeholders.  You should put your placeholders in a Map with the value being the realValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix issue what I did is I placed the string builder replacing code section out side the for loop and also use Hashmap to map placeholder and realValue.

```
 @Override
    public void getdata(String dynamicJson) throws IOException {


        // create object mapper instance
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


        // convert JSON string to Java Object
        DynamicJson dynamicJson1 = mapper.readValue(dynamicJson, DynamicJson.class);


        int id = dynamicJson1.getMessageId();


        Optional<Notification> notification = notificationRepository.findById(id);

        List<PlaceHolder> placeHolders = notification.get().getPlaceHolders();

        //Changed
        HashMap<String, String> hash_map = new HashMap<String, String>();


        String message = notification.get().getMessage();


        for (int i = 0; i < placeHolders.size(); i++) {


            String placeholder = placeHolders.get(i).getValue();
            String realValue = dynamicJson1.getPlaceholders().get(placeholder).toString();

            //Changed
            hash_map.put(placeholder, realValue);

        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(message.length());
        String delimiters = "+-*/(),. ";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(message, delimiters, true);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String w = st.nextToken();
            if (hash_map.containsKey(w)) {
                result.append(hash_map.get(w));
            } else {
                result.append(w);
            }
        }


        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is your outer for loop. You loop over your placeholders. You should put your placeholders in a Map with the value being the realValue.  Something like this:

```
Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>();
placeHolders.forEach(i -> replacements.put(i, dynamicJson1.getPlaceholders().get(i).toString()));
            
String sentence = "You have succuessfully subscribe to <PACKNAME> and it will be <PACKTYPE> package";
            
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(sentence.length());
String delimiters = "+-*/(),. ";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sentence, delimiters, true);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
   String w = st.nextToken();
   if (replacements.containsKey(w)) {
      result.append(replacements.get(w));
   } else {
      result.append(w);
   }
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Edit:
here is the population of the map without using lambda:

```
for(String placeHolder: placeHolders) {
    replacements.put(placeHolder, dynamicJson1.getPlaceholders().get(placeHolder).toString()))
}
```

Comment: I replaced your core directly since I don't have much experience about lamda anyway it asked required type string but provided type is placeholder  replacements.put(i,  then add i.getValue() but got an exception

Comment: @HashanR, what exception did you get?

Comment: "trace": "java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat com.hashanr.notificationsender.service.NotificationServiceImpl.lambda$getdata$0(NotificationServiceImpl.java:66)\r\n\tat java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)\r\n\tat com.hashanr.notificationsender.service.NotificationServiceImpl.getdata(NotificationServiceImpl.java:66)\r\n\tat com.hashanr.notificationsender.controller.NotificationController.getObject(NotificationController.java:28)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\

Comment: I will add full code so that you can get clear idea. anyway I'm new to spring boot and java

Comment: @HashanR, can you inspect your dynamicJson1 object to make sure it has the proper data?

Comment: Yes it check it has proper data and code was working without any exception or error with for loop

Comment: This is json object and I get placeHolders using dynamicJson1

{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Test-Name",
    "message": "You have succuessfully subscribe to <PACKNAME> and it will be <PACKTYPE> package",
    "tags": [
        {
            "tagId": 9,
            "value": "Youtube"
        }
    ],
    "placeHolders": [
        {
            "phId": 8,
            "value": "<PACKNAME>"
        },
        {
            "phId": 9,
            "value": "<PACKTYPE>"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @HashanR could you supply your DynamicJson class too?

Comment: I've added entity class as well. I really appreciate your support and this means a lot. I'm stuck on  final stage of the project due to this issue.

Comment: I could overcome issue after I placed string builder string replacement codes outside the loop. Appreciate for your support